# VS2010 LoadFrame fails with error 1401in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have this code :

```
CMainFrame* pFrame = NULL;
    fsnew1 (pFrame, CMainFrame);
    m_pMainWnd = pFrame;     

    if (FALSE == pFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | FWS_ADDTOTITLE, NULL, NULL))
    {
      DWORD err = GetLastError();// error code 1401 is returned
        return FALSE;
    }
```

In debug mode the if condition is false and so no error is there and my dialog frame gets loade successfully.
But in release mode if condition gets true as LoadFrame returns false and frame never gets loaded.

What may be the issue?

Comment: 1401 = Your menu handle is invalid.

Comment: Yes I know, but is that so? its working in debug mode.

Comment: Recompiler your resource file. Maybe some storage is now no longer initialized with a constant value. And this causes the error. Debug it. You can also Debug a release mode program. Just create PDB files for it.

Comment: recompiling .rc file didnt helped. I am debugging the project in release mode (F5), program gets exited with code 0 after Frame fails to load.

Comment: Set breakpoints to LoadFrame and debug into it.

Comment: If you're concerned about the menu resource, try this.  Exit visual studio; delete the .aps and .res files with the same name as the resource (.rc) file.  Open visual studio and rebuild.

Comment: @rrirower Did what you said. and this solved it. No idea why. :D

Comment: The .res and .aps files are a by-product of resource compilation.  It's not unusual for them to get out of sync with what's actually in the .rc file especially if modifications are made manually and not through the resource editor.  Deleting those files will force the resource compiler to rebuild them and thus put them back in sync.

Comment: @rrirower: please put your comment as an answer, so that it is visible to other members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments...

The .res and .aps files are a by-product of resource compilation. It's not unusual for them to get out of sync with what's actually in the .rc file especially if modifications are made manually and not through the resource editor. Deleting those files will force the resource compiler to rebuild them and thus put them back in sync