# LoadFrame (MFC) failing only in Australia

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Our team has a bug that has stumped us.

The following code returns false:

```
    CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;
if (!pMainFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME))
{
    AfxMessageBox(GetStr(IDS_MAINFRM_FAIL_TO_LOAD));
    ASSERT(FALSE);
    return FALSE;
}
```

We're compiling using VS2010, and we do have the RogueWave Stingray component installed.  The CMainFrame is a CBCGPMDIFrameWnd which is based off of a CMDIFrameWnd and made by [BCGSoft](https://www.bcgsoft.com/).

We have our software running on about 100 machines globally with no issues.  Its running on Windows 7-10 x86 & x64.  It always worked, until this week.  A small group of people in Mildura, Australia have reported an issue.  For all of them, running WIN7x86Enterprise and Win10x64Home, the code snippet above returns false.  I personally inspected one of their machines (Win10x64Home) and everything seems to be in order.

I've tried [deleting the RES and APS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240923/vs2010-loadframe-fails-with-error-1401in-release-mode) for the project.  That didn't help.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  I'm open to educated guesses.

Thanks in advance!

PS: New Info:
It looks like its a time issue.  On the computer, everything UTC+ fails, and UTC0 & UTC- pass.  We aren't sure why.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Add `m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;` before `LoadFrame` (I assume you are in `CWinApp::InitInstance`

Comment: Random ideas: change time zones and localization (language etc) settings on a computer outside aus to match the computer inside, and vice versa.  Use a vpn to make the non-aus computer be on the aus computer network, and vice versa.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I'm trying your suggestion.  I'll report back.

Comment: @Yakk: I'll try your suggestion too.

Comment: @Yakk: I changed all the settings on my dev machine to Australia, and our App ran fine, but Visual Studio messed up something horrible.  You MAY be on to something.

Comment: @Yakk: after returning my settings to USA in attempt to compile, now I get the error my client is getting.  Wish me luck.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: your suggestion made the dialog not pop up.  I'll be avoiding your suggestion.

Comment: I should have avoid your question. This is probably a joke, claiming that you have narrowed down the problem to Australia.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: This is NOT a joke.  Its an international date line issue.  We're working on it.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were doing TimeDate calcs on an elapsed timestamp using the epoch as a starting point.  **MFC doesn't allow dates before the epoch**, so all UTC+ failed the date creation.  This bug has been fixed.  Thank you to everyone.

Here is the code that was causing the issue (fixed).  We added one day on for everything to work.  CTime::CTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0) w/ UTC+ ,making it before 1/1/1970 in London, fails.

Thanks!

```
CTime t1 = CTime::CTime(yearInt,monthInt,dayInt,0,0,0);
CTime t2 = CTime::CTime(1970,1,2,0,0,0);
CTimeSpan timeSpan = t1-t2;
versionDate = timeSpan.GetDays() + 1;
```

Comment: The answer isn't clear. What types for the calculation was used? COleDateTime "nearly" allows everything ;)

Comment: @xMRi: Do you like the new answer?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with LoadFrame failing on a select number of machines (all Windows 10 in different timezones, including Australia). How/why did the UTC+ issue reveal itself in LoadFrame?

Comment: I was calling CTime() during the load frame.  The issue was that the time was before the epoch, which CTime doesn't allow.  If you can be more specific, I can help you more.

Comment: @DanG Thanks. Well that can't be my problem so... I've tracked it down to the registry entries for DockingManager. Once their deleted the app starts no problem. It's a very strange problem, and different to yours. When I know more I'll probably ask a question formally. Thanks again!